# Coloring the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I try to color the diagonal of a matrix.

```
\begin{equation}
    C=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

All I found was related to rows and columns (see. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69714/74926
and
http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1289)
Could someone may help.

---

I already found this. Sadly the line overlay the text and the brackets.
Some further help would be great.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] 
    \node[anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \tikzmark{top}{1} & \tikzmark{top2}{1} & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & \tikzmark{bottom2}{1} \\
  \tikzmark{end}{1} & 0 & \tikzmark{bottom}{1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[red,line width=1mm,line cap=round] (top.north west) -- (bottom.south east);
     \draw[red,line width=1mm,line cap=round] (top2.north west) -- (bottom2.south east);
     \draw[red,line width=1mm,line cap=round] (end.north west) -- (end.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] 
    \node[anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \tikzmark{top}{1} & \tikzmark{top2}{1} & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & \tikzmark{bottom2}{1} \\
  \tikzmark{end}{1} & 0 & \tikzmark{bottom}{1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[opacity=.4,line width=3mm,line cap=round] (top.center) -- (bottom.center);
     \draw[opacity=.4,line width=3mm,line cap=round] (top2.center) -- (bottom2.center);
     \draw[opacity=.4,line width=3mm,line cap=round] (end.center) -- (end.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Welcome, you can use something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\newcommand\RED{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    C=
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \RED 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & \RED 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & \RED 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [opacity=.4,line width=3mm,line cap=round] 
              (1-1.center) -- (3-3.center)
              (1-2.center) -- (2-3.center)
              (3-1.center) -- (3-1.center) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]