# Rectangle box around elements of matrix

Tags: matrices

Here, I wish to draw a rectangle around the principal diagonal elements (red colored) of the below matrix.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}

Here, I wish to draw a rectangle around the principal diagonal elements 
(red colored) of the below matrix.
\[
  A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \textcolor{red}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    1 & \textcolor{red}{2} & 3 & 4\\
    1 & 2 & \textcolor{red}{3} & 4\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & \textcolor{red}{4}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Coloring the diagonal of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234989/5764), [highlighting diagonal of a square matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30032/5764), [How can I color/highlight the diagonal of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284214/5764), [How can I highlight elements in a matrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257043/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Output of the first code]

With use of `nicematrix`  package you obtain above result after two compilation ot he following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}llll}[margin=3mm]
\Block[draw=red]{}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & \Block[draw=red]{}{2} & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & \Block[draw=red]{}{3} & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \Block[draw=red]{}{4} \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

or like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}cccc}[margin,extra-margin = 1pt]
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=red, rounded corners=2pt, inner ysep = 0pt,
       rotate fit=-38, fit = (1-1) (4-4) ] {} ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice work by you, actually i want to draw a single rectangle which covers all four elements please don't mind.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, see if added example is what you looking for.

Comment: Sir, this is exactly what i was looking. Thanks a lot for giving response to my question for so many times, i hope that in future i will  get benefit of your knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions with `pstricks`: one with a simple frame around the diagonal elements and another which adds a coloured background. The `pst-node` module has a dedicated command for that – `\ncbox`:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath, xcolor}
    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

    \[
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
       \rnode{B}{\color{red}{1}} & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        1 & \color{red}{2} & 3 & 4\\
        1 & 2 & \textcolor{red}{3} & 4\\
        1 & 2 & 3 & \rnode{E}{\color{red}{4}}
      \end{bmatrix}
    \ncbox[linecolor =VioletRed, boxsize=5pt, linearc=0.05]{B}{E}
    \]
    \[
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
       \rnode{B}{\color{red}{1}} & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        1 & \color{red}{2} & 3 & 4\\
        1 & 2 & \textcolor{red}{3} & 4\\
        1 & 2 & 3 & \rnode{E}{\color{red}{4}}
      \end{bmatrix}
    \ncbox[linecolor =IndianRed, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=MistyRose, opacity=0.2, boxsize=5pt, linearc=0.05, nodesep=0.8pt]{B}{E}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

If you do no want the diagonal frame to touch the brackets, you can, omong other possibilities, change the value of the \ncbox parameter `linearc=0.18`to have round extremities, or nest a simple `matrix` in `bmatrix` and add some spacingon each side, like this:

```
      \[
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
        \:\begin{matrix}
       \rnode{B}{\color{red}{1}} & 2 & 3 & 4\\
        1 & \color{red}{2} & 3 & 4\\
        1 & 2 & \textcolor{red}{3} & 4\\
        1 & 2 & 3 & \rnode{E}{\color{red}{4}}
        \end{matrix}\:
      \end{bmatrix}
    \ncbox[linecolor =IndianRed, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=MistyRose, opacity=0.2, boxsize=5pt, linearc=0.05, nodesep=0.8pt]{B}{E}
    \]
```

[image]

Comment: This is also great effort. This is also useful. But why does the rectangle is touching both brackets of matrix?

Comment: That is because of the geometry of the figure: pstricks figures are superimposed on an existing normal matrix, and the value of `\arraycolsep` is too small (5pt), That's why I added a small opacity in the version with background.  You can change \arraycolsep beforehand or add   empty columns at the beginning and end of the matrix, or nest a simple `matrix` environment with some spacing on the left and on the right in a `bmatrix`.

Comment: Agree with you comment. Now I can adjust spacing. Once again thanks for coming across my question and for valuable comment.

Comment: I've added two more possibilities.

Comment: @Bernard I am getting the error `Package auto-pst-pdf Error: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}` on compiling your code. Any help?

Comment: I also have had problems with auto-pst-pdf for some times. There new options to compile pstricks code with pdflatex but I haven't tested them yet. The simplest would be to compile with `xelatex` (no need for auto-pst-pdf in this case).

Comment: and if i want the last node in 4 appear open, i.e. start close in 1 and end in 4 open, how do this