# How do the following matrix product

Tags: matrices, circles, draft, xrightarrow

I am interesting about drafting the following in LaTeX. I am not so much expert in this, i am going to attach the code to generate the vector and matrix, and after that I am going to attach my desired output.

Code:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_k\end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_1&0&\ldots&0\\ 0&\varepsilon_2&\ldots&0\\0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&\ldots&\varepsilon_N\\ 
   \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
```

Output:

[image]

So what I want is a circle on the first and last element of vector (a1,..,ak) and an arrow that goes from a1 to the rectangle of first row of matrix, the same for the last row. Sorry if the circle is made in that bad way, I have done it manually, of course is preferred a circle draft in a better way.

Comment: Using `tikzmark` library is a very nice way to do it. And also, feel free to look at the *Related* menu on the right, where some helpful answers would be found.

Comment: @SebGlav What do you suggest to try on the search bar? I have tried, without result for this kind of problem..

Comment: Searching (here) for "\tikzmark matrix" did well.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525421/highlighting-rows-columns-diagonals-in-matrix for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{(c)(cccc)}[create-medium-nodes,nullify-dots]
a_1    & \epsilon_1 & 0          & \cdots & 0 \\
a_2    & 0          & \epsilon_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\Vdots & 0          & 0          & \cdots & 0 \\
a_k    & 0          & 0          & \cdots & \epsilon_n \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [cyan,inner sep=1pt]
    \node [circle,draw,fit=(1-1)] (A) {} ;
    \node [circle,draw,fit=(4-1)] (B) {} ;
    \node [draw,rounded corners, fit = (1-2-medium) (1-5-medium)] (C) {} ;
    \node [draw,rounded corners, fit = (4-2-medium) (4-5-medium)] (D) {} ;
    \draw [->] (A.north) to [bend left] (C.north west) ; 
    \draw [->] (B.south) to [bend right] (D.south west) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

With pure Ti*k*Z:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm,
FIT/.style = {inner sep=1pt, draw=red, fit=#1},
arr/.style = {draw=blue, -Straight Barb,semithick},
M/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
            nodes= {minimum size=1em, inner sep=1pt, anchor=base},
            column sep=0pt,
            row sep=3pt,
            left delimiter=(,
            right delimiter=),
            inner sep=2pt}    
                        ]
\matrix (m) [M] 
{|[circle,draw=red]| a_1\\
    a_2\\ \vdots \\ 
 |[circle,draw=red]|a_k\\};
%
\matrix (n) [M,right=of m]
{\varepsilon_1  & 0             & \ldots    & 0             \\
    0           &\varepsilon_2  & \ldots    & 0             \\
    0           & 0             & \ldots    & 0             \\
    0           & 0             & \ldots    & \varepsilon_N \\
};
\node (n1) [FIT=(n-1-1) (n-1-4)] {};
\node (n2) [FIT=(n-4-1) (n-4-4)] {};
%
\draw[arr] (m-1-1) to[bend  left=45] (n1);
\draw[arr] (m-4-1) to[bend right=45] (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility with a simple `pstricks` code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node} 

\begin{document}

    \[ \psset{linecolor=LightSteelBlue, linearc=0.1, boxsize=0.25, nodesep=1.5pt, arrowinset=0.12} \begin{pmatrix}\circlenode{a1}{a_1}\\a_2\\\vdots\\\circlenode{ak}{a_k}\end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}\,\Rnode{e1}{\varepsilon_1}&0&\ldots&\Rnode{f1}{0}\\ \, 0 & \varepsilon_2&\ldots&0\\ \,0&0&\ldots&0\\ \,\Rnode{fN}{0}&0&\ldots&\Rnode{eN}{\varepsilon_N}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \ncbox{e1}{f1}\ncbox{eN}{fN}
    \nccurve[angle=90, nodesepA=0, nodesepB=5pt]{->}{a1}{e1}
    \nccurve[angle=-90, nodesepA=0, nodesepB=3pt]{->}{ak}{fN}
    \]%
```

\end{document}
[image]

Comment: @F.Pantigny: Thanks for the edit (on ne se relit jamais assez…)

Answer (score 2):

And now with a simple Ti*k*Z solution, using `tikzmark` library, as suggested in my comment (note: needs to be compiled a couple of times to compute then display correctly).

[image: nodes on matrix]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}
        \begin{pmatrix}\tikzmarknode{A1}{a_1}\\a_2\\\vdots\\\tikzmarknode{AK}{a_k}\end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \tikzmarknode{E1}{\varepsilon_1}&0&\ldots&\tikzmarknode{0A}{0}\\
            0&\varepsilon_2&\ldots&0\\
            0&0&\ldots&0\\
            \tikzmarknode{0B}{0}&0&\ldots&\tikzmarknode{EN}{\varepsilon_N}\\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align}
    
    \tikzset{
        circ/.style={inner sep=6pt, outer sep=0pt, line width=1pt, circle, draw=cyan},
        rect/.style={inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, line width=1pt, rounded corners=5pt, draw=cyan}
        }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,cyan]
        \node[circ] (a1) at (A1) {};
        \node[circ] (ak) at (AK) {};
        
        \node[rect,fit=(E1)(0A)] (line1) {};
        \node[rect,fit=(EN)(0B)] (line4) {};
        
        \draw[-latex,line width=1pt] (a1.north) to[out=60,in=120] (line1.160);
        \draw[-latex,line width=1pt] (ak.south) to[out=-60,in=-120] (line4.-160);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```