# How can I color/highlight the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: tables

I have a table such as the one below

```
\begin{tiny}\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&0.906&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&0.127&0.098&0.958\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tiny}
```

How can I highlight the diagonal, the first row and the first column with different colours?

Comment: Package `colortable` or `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and `\cellcolor` command and `\begin{tiny}...\end{tiny}` does work, but it's 'wrong'

Comment: I can't understand how this can be considered a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/matrix-change-row-or-column-background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy with `colortbl` (loaded via `xcolor`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{red!20}}l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}%
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&\cellcolor{green}0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&0.906&\cellcolor{green}0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&0.127&0.098&\cellcolor{green}0.958\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For getting automatically what you want you just need to use the following code; it's necessary to change the name of the environment, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{matlabtabular}[1]
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl 
   {
    \tl_tail:n { #1 }
   }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl { | >{\columncolor{red!20}} }
  \angelino_matlabtab:VV \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl \BODY
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq { \hline } { #2 }
  % the first item is empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % the last item is empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % separate the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % fix the first row
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline\rowcolor{blue!20} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
    \int_zero:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
     {
      \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
      \int_compare:nTF { \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int == \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \cellcolor{green} ####1 }
       }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & ####1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn { VV }
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{matlabtabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&0.906&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&0.127&0.098&0.958\\\hline
\end{matlabtabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Note that this makes some assumptions on the environment's contents. The argument should begin with `|` that's changed into `|>{\columncolor{red!20}}`. It is also assumed that every row ends with `\\\hline`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the latex code of the matrix it was been exported from Matlab because the matrix have many row and columns.

Comment: @LucaAngelino My crystal ball didn't see that. And I can't see how to do it, unless Matlab has facilities for adding the necessary bits.

Comment: I would highlight it automatically with an table style

Comment: I don't know if it is possible!

Comment: @LucaAngelino Look now.

Comment: Your code is very powerful!!

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, here is how to do this in ConTeXt. I think that ConTeXt provides a much nicer separation of content and presentation for tables.

```
\definecolor[lightblue]  [b=1,r=0.8,g=0.8]
\definecolor[lightred]   [r=1,b=0.8,g=0.8]
\definecolor[lightgreen] [g=1,r=0.8,b=0.8]

\startsetups diagonal
  \setupTABLE[offset=0.5em]
  \dorecurse{20}% Assuming there are no more than 20 rows
    {\setupTABLE[\recurselevel][\recurselevel][background=color,backgroundcolor=lightgreen]}
  \setupTABLE[column][first][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightred, style=bold]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightblue, style=bold]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startTABLE[setups=diagonal]
  \NC       \NC ciao  \NC ciao2 \NC ciao3 \NC \NR
  \NC ciao  \NC 0.815 \NC 0.913 \NC 0.287 \NC \NR
  \NC ciao2 \NC 0.906 \NC 0.632 \NC 0.547 \NC \NR
  \NC ciao3 \NC 0.127 \NC 0.098 \NC 0.958 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do that in an automatic way by using the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

Moreover, you will have a perfect output: the rules won't seem to disappear in some PDF viewers at somme levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { matlabtabular } { O { } m ! O { } }
  { 
    \begin{NiceTabular}[#1, #3, hvlines] { #2 }
      \CodeBefore          
         \columncolor{red!15}{1}
         \rowcolor{blue!15}{1}
         \foreach \x in { 2,...,\arabic{iRow} } { \cellcolor{green!15}{\x-\x} } 
      \Body
  }
  { \end{NiceTabular} }


\begin{document}

\begin{matlabtabular}{lccc}
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\
\textbf{ciao2}&0.906&0.632&0.547\\
\textbf{ciao3}&0.127&0.098&0.958\\
\end{matlabtabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Could it be possible to also apply the `\textbf`macro automatically?

Comment: It's possible to put `>{\bfseries}l` instead of `l` in the preamble of the array (for the first column) but, as of now, there is nothing in `nicematrix` to specify formatting for a whole row. I will think of that for a new version of `nicematrix`.

Comment: Good idea. This could give a taste of CSS formating to `nicematrix`.