# How can update this code for print number with different colors?

Tags: tables, highlighting, expl3

I have this code for highlight the diagonal, the first row and the first column with different colours! (This code has been build from egreg on this community :-D in a past question)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{matlabtabular}[1]
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl 
   {
    \tl_tail:n { #1 }
   }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl { | >{\columncolor{red!20}} }
  \angelino_matlabtab:VV \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl \BODY
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq { \hline } { #2 }
  % the first item is empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % the last item is empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % separate the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % fix the first row
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline\rowcolor{blue!20} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
    \int_zero:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
     {
      \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
      \int_compare:nTF { \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int == \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \cellcolor{green} ####1 }
       }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & ####1 }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn { VV }
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{matlabtabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&5.3&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&-30&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&20&-60&0.958\\\hline
\end{matlabtabular}

\end{document}
```

How can improve this code so that if a number is not on diagonal is >0 the number is print in blue and if the number is <0 the number is print in red???????

Comment: None of the numbers in your example are less than 0.

Comment: In the exsampe, but the table generate from matlab have number less than 0

Comment: The problem is, that the whole stuff is constructed as a token list, making the query `\fp_compare:nNnTF` difficult, in my point of view.

Comment: I am not an latex expert but this code is very powerful for my task.
I need only this small improve! If it is not possible I must impreve the code that generate the table

Comment: The point is that your minimal example should set up the problem. If that problem involves distinguishing numbers greater than zero from those less than zero, then you want your example to include numbers of each kind. What's the point of the example numbers if a solution which works for the MWE (by making them all blue) won't work for your real case (where some should be red)?

Comment: Could you please include a link to the previous question where the code came from...

Comment: I've added the `expl3` tag, since the whole code is `expl3`

Comment: The first question was http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284214/how-can-i-color-highlight-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix 
Now I have update the table with value less than 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{matlabtabular}[1]
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl 
   {
    \tl_tail:n { #1 }
   }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl { | >{\columncolor{red!20}} }
  \angelino_matlabtab:VV \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl \BODY
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq { \hline } { #2 }
  % the first item is empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % the last item is empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % separate the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % fix the first row
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline\rowcolor{blue!20} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
    \int_zero:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
     {
      \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
      \int_compare:nTF { \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int == \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \cellcolor{green} ####1 }
       }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \angelino_print_number:n { ####1 } }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_print_number:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl { \\ }
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \\ } { }
    \__angelino_print_number:V \l_tmpa_tl
    \\
   }
   {
    \__angelino_print_number:V \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__angelino_print_number:n
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 > 0 }
   {
    \textcolor{blue}{$#1$}
   }
   {
    \textcolor{red}{$#1$}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__angelino_print_number:n { V }
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentcol_int
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_currentrow_int
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlab_preamble_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{matlabtabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&-0.906&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&-0.127&0.098&0.958\\\hline
\end{matlabtabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With some more work we can add customization of colors; in the new optional argument to `\begin{matlabtabular}` you can specify colors for

header
   legend
   diag
   positive
   negative

Each should be of the form `<key>=<color>` like in the example below. The default are

```
header=blue!20,
legend=red!20,
diag=green,
positive=., % normalcolor
negative=., % normalcolor
```

like in the first specification you gave.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{matlabtabular}[2][]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { angelino/matlabtab } { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_angelino_matlabtab_preamble_tl 
   {
    \tl_tail:n { #2 }
   }
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_preamble_tl { | >{\columncolor{\l_angelino_matlabtab_legend_tl}} }
  \angelino_matlabtab:VV \l_angelino_matlabtab_preamble_tl \BODY
 }

\keys_define:nn { angelino/matlabtab }
 {
  header   .tl_set:N  = \l_angelino_matlabtab_head_tl,
  header   .initial:n = blue!20,
  legend   .tl_set:N  = \l_angelino_matlabtab_legend_tl,
  legend   .initial:n = red!20,
  diag     .tl_set:N  = \l_angelino_matlabtab_diag_tl,
  diag     .initial:n = green,
  positive .tl_set:N = \l_angelino_matlabtab_positive_tl,
  positive .initial:n = .,
  negative .tl_set:N = \l_angelino_matlabtab_negative_tl,
  negative .initial:n = .,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq { \hline } { #2 }
  % the first item is empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % the last item is empty
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % separate the first row
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  % fix the first row
  \tl_put_left:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline\rowcolor{\l_angelino_matlabtab_head_tl} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentrow_int
    \int_zero:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentcol_int
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \tl_put_right:NV \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
     {
      \int_incr:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentcol_int
      \int_compare:nTF { \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentcol_int == \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentrow_int }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \cellcolor{\l_angelino_matlabtab_diag_tl} ####1 }
       }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { & \angelino_print_number:n { ####1 } }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl { \hline }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \angelino_matlabtab:nn { VV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \angelino_print_number:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl { \\ }
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { \\ } { }
    \__angelino_print_number:V \l_tmpa_tl
    \\
   }
   {
    \__angelino_print_number:V \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__angelino_print_number:n
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 >= 0 }
   {
    \textcolor{\l_angelino_matlabtab_positive_tl}{$#1$}
   }
   {
    \textcolor{\l_angelino_matlabtab_negative_tl}{$#1$}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__angelino_print_number:n { V }
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentcol_int
\int_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_currentrow_int
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_row_seq
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_angelino_matlabtab_preamble_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{matlabtabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&-0.906&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&-0.127&0.098&0.958\\\hline
\end{matlabtabular}

\bigskip

\begin{matlabtabular}[positive=blue,negative=red]{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\textbf{ciao}&\textbf{ciao2}&\textbf{ciao3}\\\hline
\textbf{ciao}&0.815&0.913&0.278\\\hline
\textbf{ciao2}&-0.906&0.632&0.547\\\hline
\textbf{ciao3}&-0.127&0.098&0.958\\\hline
\end{matlabtabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is really spectacle

Comment: The last questions is if I rename this as \NewEnviron{matlabtabular2} and the last (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284214/how-can-i-color-highlight-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix) leave \NewEnviron{matlabtabular} for have two type of table the compile generate error! :-( why?????

Comment: @LucaAngelino Doing things this way is not the best approach. I'll think to a more general setting. The main obstacle is the requirement of not touching the body of the table as generated by MatLab, of course.

Comment: with matlab I can add simply text first and later the values!

Comment: @LucaAngelino I added a new version so you can customize the colors.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I thought that in latex, such as in html, there is a way for add a table with an style name and by changing the style name I can obtain every customization