# tikz matrix delimiters when nodes size is defined by "minimum size"

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, delimiters

studding  [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/matrix-change-row-or-column-background) i find unexpected behavior of `tikz` matrix delimiter: if the size of math nodes are determined by `text width=...` and `text height=...`, than delimiters work as expected, however, if i replace them with `minimum size=...` gives error `!missing } inserted.. <inserted text> }`. test example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand\x{\times}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
         nodes={rectangle, %draw, very thin,
                minimum size=1.2em, text depth=0.25ex,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                left delimiter=(, right delimiter=),
                fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1,
                anchor=center},
         column sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
         row sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
         column 2/.append style = {nodes={fill=cyan!50}},
         row 2/.append style = {nodes={fill=cyan!50}},
         row 2 column 2/.append style={nodes={fill=cyan}},
         ]
{
a_1 & \x  & a_3 \\
a_4 & \x  & a_6 \\
a_7 & \x  & a_9 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

if i comment definition of delimiters, example gives:

[image]

do i miss something or doing wrong?

Comment: I get errors rather from `ampersand replacement` and the `left delimiter`/`right delimiter` line. `minimum size` works as well for me as `text width` or `text height`.

Comment: ups, line with `ampersant replacement` was left from some my experiments ... it should be erased. done now in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place `left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)` outside of the `nodes` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand\x{\times}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
         nodes={rectangle, %draw, very thin,
                minimum size=1.2em, text depth=0.25ex,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1,
                anchor=center},
         column sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
         row sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
         column 2/.append style = {nodes={fill=cyan!50}},
         row 2/.append style = {nodes={fill=cyan!50}},
         row 2 column 2/.append style={nodes={fill=cyan}},
         left delimiter={(}, right delimiter={)}
         ]
{
a_1 & \x  & a_3 \\
a_4 & \x  & a_6 \\
a_7 & \x  & a_9 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what a stupid mistake ... thank you for finding it in my example. howver, now i'm confused. if you look @CarlaTeX answer in given ling, and there replace line `nodes={text width=.75em, text height=1.75ex, text depth=.5ex, align=center}` with `nodes={minimum size=1.5em, text depth=.5ex, align=center}`, you will receive error: `Missing $ inserted <inserted text> $`.before accepting your answer, i should check all my experiments again, for now +1 :-)

Comment: Jasper Habicht, i done even more stupid error when testing @carlatex answer :-(. in it i had combination `minimum size=...,align=center` which is of course wrong ... what embarrassing!