# Coloring columns in blockarray

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, columns, rowcolor

I'd like to color individual columns in a 3x3 matrix created using `\blockarray`. I wish to give one color to the first column, and a second color to the 2nd and 3rd column. I found the answers two [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/matrix-change-row-or-column-background) helpful, however, they do not seem to solve my problem.

However, I somehow cannot get the first answer using `\columncolor` from the `xcolor` package to work in this environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray} % blockarrays; 

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
        \begin{block}{\BAmulticolumn{3}{>{}c}}
            \oint_{S^\textnormal{rec}}&\\
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{(>{\scriptstyle}>{\columncolor{olive!20}}c>{\scriptstyle}c>{\scriptstyle}c)}
            a &\cdots & b\\
            \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
            cd &\cdots&N_\textnormal e\\
        \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It throws the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\BA@.[10002,1]u ...\BA@bdollar \hfil \columncolor
{olive!20}\scriptstyle
l.19 \end{align*}
```

The second answer using the package `hf-tikz` and `\tikzmark` is also not solving the issue, as it fails for column entries of different lengths.

Can someone help me getting this to work in the `\blockarray` environment?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to solve the problem with `\blockarray`, but I think you can reach your desired result with a TikZ `matrix of math nodes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray} % blockarrays; 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {$\oint_{S^\textnormal{rec}}$};
    \matrix[
        below=-2pt of A,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes={
            text width=1.2em, 
            text height=1.4ex,
            text depth=.5ex, 
            align=center, 
            font=\scriptsize, 
        },
        left delimiter={(},right delimiter={)},
        column 1/.style={nodes={fill={olive!20}}}
        ] {
        a &[6pt]\cdots &[6pt] b\\
        \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\[-4pt]
        cd &\cdots&N_\textnormal e\\
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,margin]
  \Block{1-*}{\oint_{S^{\text{rec}}}} \\
  \Block[fill=olive!20,rounded-corners]{3-1}{} a &  \cdots & b \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  cd & \cdots & N_{\text{e}}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

The same with the system of `nicematrix` for the dotted lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,margin,xdots/shorten=2mm]
  \Block{1-*}{\oint_{S^{\text{rec}}}} \\
  \Block[fill=olive!20,rounded-corners]{3-1}{} a &  \Cdots & b \\
  \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
  cd & \Cdots & N_{\text{e}}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]